# Animate UISlider on touch up event

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create an animation for the UISlider, when action event TouchUpIside

```
- (IBAction)touchUpInside:(UISlider *)sender {
        //animations slow value sender.value to value 0

        sender.value = -1;
        [sender layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: you question title makes no sense and you description is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the slider in an animation block, and also in the animation block tell the slider to lay itself out:

```
- (IBAction)sliderDidReceiveTouchUpInside:(UISlider *)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        sender.value = 0;
        [sender layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Note that if the user drags the slider knob, and then drags her finger away from the slider, and then lifts her finger, the slider will receive a “touch up **outside**”, not a “touch up inside”.  That's a different event.